# Windows 10 Wi-Fi Networks not showing up

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

I recently tried to get my old Gigabyte GN-WPKG PCI WLAN card to work again, as I moved my computer and was too lazy to lay new cables. Device was working perfectly, all the drivers were correct, but the Wi-Fi tab didn't show up in Settings. After a lot of troubleshooting, I started the WLAN AutoConfig Service and it appeared.

Now, however, there are no Wi-Fi networks showing up inside the settings. Also, the Advanced Settings link is gone (that I assume should be there).  Basically, I'm stuck with this:

[image: Settings]

Anyone have any ideas what to do? I already tried to delete a registry key that might have been interfering with the Wi-Fi, according to [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/fix-no-wi-fi-available-after-windows-10-upgrade-issue-heres-how/), but the registry key isn't found. Also tried Uninstalling device driver and restarting, but to no avail.

Comment: Might need to find a windows 10 driver for it...

Answer (score 0):

Open up Device Manager and find your wireless card, right click it and select update drivers. If that doesn't work, install the latest driver's from it's manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the device you are using [Here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Enterprise/Wireless-Product/GN-WPKG-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) , it appears that the last supported driver was for Windows Vista. This card may simply be incompatible with Windows 10 which could be the cause.